# How to correctly get Azure Dev Ops to gate and display code coverage diff for a Pull Request

Tags: azure, azure-devops, code-coverage

I am trying to use azure dev ops to do two things:

1. Display html versions of code coverage diff changes to the user
2. Gate pull requests on new coding reaching a certain coverage threshold

**How do I make code coverage work for both of these scenarios for Azure Dev Ops?**

I have followed the MS instructions here for enabling Code Coverage gating

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/test/codecoverage-for-pullrequests?view=azure-devops

The instructions here, dont allow for gating because of different code coverage formats:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/dotnet-core?view=azure-devops&tabs=dotnetfive#collect-code-coverage

I have the following ADO YAML  (Note the codecoverage.exe is deprecated so I am not using that):

```
      - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2  
        displayName: 'Unit Test .sln'
        inputs:
          command: 'test'
          workingDirectory: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\src\'
          arguments: '--configuration debug --logger trx --collect "Code coverage" --no-build'
          publishTestResults: false
      
      - task: PublishTestResults@2
        displayName: 'Publish test results'
        condition: succeededOrFailed()
        inputs:
          testResultsFormat: VSTest
          testResultsFiles: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\**\*.trx'
          failTaskOnFailedTests: true
          
      - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
        displayName: "Install CodeCoverage Console"
        inputs:
          command: "custom"
          custom: "tool"
          arguments: 'install dotnet-coverage --global'
          
      - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
        displayName: "Install CodeCoverage Report Generator"
        inputs:
          command: "custom"
          custom: "tool"
          arguments: 'install --global dotnet-reportgenerator-globaltool'    
          
      - task: CmdLine@2
        displayName: 'Merge coverage reports'
        condition: succeededOrFailed()
        inputs:
          script: |
             dotnet-coverage merge -r -o $(Agent.TempDirectory)\coverage.cobertura.xml -f cobertura -l $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\coverage\logs\ -ll Verbose $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\*.coverage

      - task: CmdLine@2
        displayName: 'Generate coverage HTML'
        condition: succeededOrFailed()
        inputs: 
          script: |
            reportgenerator "-reports:$(Agent.TempDirectory)\coverage.cobertura.xml" "-targetdir:$(Agent.TempDirectory)\coverage" "-reporttypes:HtmlInline_AzurePipelines;Cobertura" -tag:$(CDP_FILE_VERSION_SEMANTIC) "-assemblyfilters:-*tests*;-*moq*"

      - task: PublishCodeCoverageResults@1
        displayName: 'Publish coverage results'
        condition: succeededOrFailed()
        inputs:
          codeCoverageTool: 'Cobertura'
          summaryFileLocation: '$(Agent.TempDirectory)/**/Cobertura.xml'
          pathToSources: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
          reportDirectory: '$(Agent.TempDirectory)/coverage'
```

Which gets me the following false positive (coverage threshold was set to 75%):

[image]
[image]

The Coverage summary is only showing the overall dll code coverage not the diff coverage for the PR:

[image]

NOTE: if I switch to using "XPlat Code Coverage" for the test I can get the html diff reports to work correctly but I no longer get the PR gating on code coverage to work (since the .coverage file is no longer generated).

Comment: *Gate pull requests on new coding reaching a certain coverage threshold*. I strongly recommend against doing that. Required code coverage percentages just results in lots of useless tests to game the number, it does nothing to reduce regressions or improve the actual quality of code being produced.